# The extended attributes are inconsistent (Windows 10 VM)

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtual-machine, uac

My setup:
[Solus](https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=solus) installed with a Windows 10 VM

---

My problem:
Whenever I want to start an application I get the error message "*The extended attributes are inconsistent*".
Also when trying to shut down the machine I get an error message like [this](https://fud.community.services.support.microsoft.com/Fud/FileDownloadHandler.ashx?fid=91c0cc4d-22ca-47e5-9f86-19554b325689) one.

---

What I did to try to solve the problem:

- Try to deactivate UAC (not possible due to problem)
- Try `sfc /scannow` (not possible. Can't open elevated cmd or Powershell/Powershell ISE)
- Windows update (no updates available)
- Deactivate all audio codecs (not possible. UAC doesn't work)
- Add new standard user
- Add new administrator

---

My specs:
The vbox file with all preferences can be found as text file [here](https://pastebin.com/PsavWMcN).
After creating the machine I installed Windows 8, upgraded to 8.1 and then upgraded to 10 (because of licensing). I never tested if the problem is present in Windows 8.x.
This is my second try with a VM. On my first try I installed Windows 10 directly (without Windows 8 and all the upgrades)

---

My question:

1. Is there a way to disable UAC without the need of exe files, cmd or
   powershell (.reg files doesn't work either)?
2. Could there be any other cause other than UAC or codecs?

Comment: If you have "Automatically hide taskbar" in Settings / Personalization / Taskbar, undo it and reboot. Is the computer fully updated?

Comment: You can disable UAC on Windows 8+ through a group policy.  Have you done that?

Comment: http://borncity.com/win/2016/12/10/windows-10-file-system-error-1073741819-extended-attributes-are-in-consistent/

Comment: @Ramhound thank you. I can use the machine now.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I already tried the methods there. I had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Came across the same error after running windows 10 update last week. Just like the OP, I was unable to do anything, even the regular fixes (disable audio, change UAC level..etc) which seems to have worked for other users failed to work for me and I was not able to even change the UAC settings.

After digging this a bit more deeper, figured that my graphics card is the culprit. I have ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5XXX series graphics card and AMD no longer provide driver updates for this one. I lost a number of features (brightness control, HDMI support..etc) which were working fine before the last windows update. So, I tried to roll-back windows but couldn't solve the UAC issue for some reason.

My system comes with switchable graphics. While reviewing the switchable graphics settings, noticed that "conscent.exe" which is part of the UAC is set to use graphics card based on power. Switched this to "Power Saving" (ie, to use on-board Intel graphics) and UAC started to work normally.

So, if anyone come across similar issue and couldn't fix by default methods, check your graphics card setting/driver. Sometimes it works if you upgrade/downgrade your graphics drivers as needed or use on-board graphics for UAC's "conscent.exe" if possible to fix the error.

Just my 2 cents :)

Comment: I also had a Radeon Card, however mine was 7xxx. That might have been the problem.